# what would be possible data type to support return value from db2/mainframe when executing code using C program

Tags: c, db2, cobol, mainframe

Random value generated in DB2/mainframe : 1111111111111111

Data type in COBOL script for return values is Decimal (15)

Data type declared as SQL_C_LONG in c program

c code fails when tries to execute db2 SP in linux for below error:

SQLSTATE: 22003 Native Error Code: 4294867297
[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0111E Numeric value out of range.
SQLSTATE=22003

Comment: The question is not precise. Is the stored-procedure written in COBOL or SQL or other language?  What is the `create procedure` definition of the parameters to the stored procedure (as distinct from the COBOL representation).

Comment: This question is a duplicate (without much improvement) of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268434/sqlstate-22003-native-error-code-4294867297-ibmcli-driver-cli0111e-numeric

Answer (score 0):

It seems to vary based on the resources I've looked at, but at least two of them define "long" as 2^31-1, which is 2,147,483,647...clearly smaller than 1,111,111,111,111,111.  It appears that the C "long long int" type is 2^63-1, which should contain that big bunch of ones with quite a bit of breathing room... 
(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no C equivalent data type for decimals, according to IBM's documentation  you have to use doubles.

[Supported Data Types in C and C++](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/r0006090.html)